# Why could different data in a table be processed with different performance?

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgresql-10, query-planner

I am experiencing a strange performance problem with Postgres 10 database.

I have such a table:

```
CREATE TABLE articles
(
    article_id bigint NOT NULL,
    content jsonb NOT NULL,
    -- a few other fields...
    CONSTRAINT articles_pkey PRIMARY KEY (article_id)
)
```

We have a Python lib (using psycopg2 driver) to access this table. It executes simple queries to the table, one of them is used for bulk downloading of content and it looks like this:

```
SELECT content FROM articles WHERE id BETWEEN $1 AND $2
```

I noticed that with some IDs it works pretty fast while with other it is 4-5 times slower. It is suitable to note, there are two main 'categories' of IDs in this table: first is range 270 million -500 million, and second is range 10000 million - 100030 million. For the first range it is 'fast' and for the second it is 'slow'. Besides larger absolute numbers withdrawing them from `int` to `bigint`, values in the second range are more 'sparse', which means in the first range values are almost consequent (with very few 'holes' of missing values) while in the second range there are much more 'holes' (average filling is 30%).

To eliminate possible influence of other libraries I conducted synthetic tests with the following query:

```
SELECT count(*), sum(length(content::text))
FROM storage.articles
WHERE article_id BETWEEN %s AND %s
```

I adjusted the length of requested chucks to equalize summary length of JSONB per request in average.

Additionally I calculate processing rate as returned `count(*)` divided by execution time. For the first range it is 800-1050 rows/s and for the second it is 120-250 rows/s. Another metric is length of processed JSON per time. As the main difficulty in the query appears to be processing of JSONB data, I assume it must be averagely same in both cases. But no: it's 7-10 MB/s vs. 1.5-2.5 MB/s.

So the issue reproduced. While it became faster in absolute values (due to absence of network transfer), the significant difference in performance persists. I compared execution plans for queries in both ranges, they look equivalent (`EXPLAIN ANALYZE`):

```
Aggregate  (cost=8046.71..8046.72 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=2924.410..2924.411 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Index Scan using articles_pkey on articles  (cost=0.57..8000.02 rows=4669 width=107) (actual time=11.482..61.258 rows=5000 loops=1)
        Index Cond: ((article_id >= 461995000) AND (article_id <= 461999999))
Planning time: 1.028 ms
Execution time: 2924.650 ms

Aggregate  (cost=6216.75..6216.76 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=17704.635..17704.636 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Index Scan using articles_pkey on articles  (cost=0.57..6180.69 rows=3606 width=107) (actual time=0.154..563.578 rows=3059 loops=1)
        Index Cond: ((article_id >= '100017010000'::bigint) AND (article_id <= '100017019999'::bigint))
Planning time: 0.404 ms
Execution time: 17704.746 ms
```

The only difference I see is conversion to `bigint` which should be one-time.

Am I missing something? How to investigate (and fix) it?

**Update 1:** Added `EXPLAIN` with `BUFFERS`:

```
Aggregate  (cost=8635.91..8635.92 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=6625.993..6625.995 rows=1 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=26847 read=3914
  ->  Index Scan using articles_pkey on articles  (cost=0.57..8573.35 rows=5005 width=107) (actual time=21.649..1128.004 rows=5000 loops=1)
        Index Cond: ((article_id >= 438000000) AND (article_id <= 438005000))
        Buffers: shared hit=4342 read=671
Planning time: 0.393 ms
Execution time: 6626.136 ms

Aggregate  (cost=5533.02..5533.03 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=33219.100..33219.102 rows=1 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=6568 read=7104
  ->  Index Scan using articles_pkey on articles  (cost=0.57..5492.96 rows=3205 width=107) (actual time=22.167..12082.624 rows=2416 loops=1)
        Index Cond: ((article_id >= '100021000000'::bigint) AND (article_id <= '100021010000'::bigint))
        Buffers: shared hit=50 read=2378
Planning time: 0.517 ms
Execution time: 33219.218 ms
```

**Update 2:** More experiments:

I conducted few more tests to exploit the approach above over all data in the table. Using a simple program, I iterate borders of segment to eventually process all data in both ranges. During this I parse the result of EXPLAIN ANALYZE and collect series of following metrics:

- Buffer hits/reads for the table.
- Buffer hits/reads for the index.
- Number of rows (from `Index Scan...`)
- Duration of execution

Based on metrics above I calculate inherited metrics:

- Disk read rate: (index reads + table reads) * 8192 / duration.
- Reads ratio: (index reads + table reads) / (index reads + table reads + index hits + table hits)
- Data rate: (index reads + table reads + index hits + table hits) * 8192 / duration

Since "density" of IDs is different in "small" and "big" ranges, I adjusted size of chunks in order to get around 5000 rows on each iteration in both cases, though my experiments show that chunk size does not really matter a lot.

The result posted above was confirmed for the *whole* first and second ranges (so it was not just caused by randomly cached data).

To eliminate cache influence I restarted Postgres server with flushing buffers:

```
postgresql stop; sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches; postgresql start
```

After this I repeated the test and got a next-to-same picture.

I rendered series from the last test into charts and post them here:

[image: 'Small' numbers range]

This is the picture for the "small" range. Disk read rate is around 10-11 MB/s uniformly across the test.

*Question: why hit rate is very high (read ratio is low) though I flushed memory buffers?*

[image: 'Big' numbers range]

This is the picture for the "big" range. It looks insane to me. In most of time disk read speed was about 2 MB/s but sometimes it jumped to 26-30 MB/s. Read ratio also varied a lot.

During the tests I verified disk read speed with `iotop` and found its indications very close to ones calculated by me. I cannot say I was monitoring it all the time, but I confirmed it when it was 2 MB/s and 22 MB/s on the second range and 10 MB/s on the first range. I also checked with `htop` that CPU was not a bottleneck and was around 3% during the tests.

The issue is reproducible on both master and slave servers. My tests were conducted on slave, while there were no any other load on DBMS, or disk activity on the host unrelated to DBMS.

My only assumption is that different fragments of data are being read with different speed due to virtualization or something, but... why is it so strictly bound to these ranges? Why is it the same on two different machines?

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you run `explain` with `buffers` options like this `explain (analyze, buffers)` and show the result?

Comment: @RomanKonoval added

Comment: The first thing that I would check if this is caused by the amount of disk IO that is done (`read` value in `Buffers:`). As you can see the `slow` case does more reads from disk. If you execute the same query again with the same parameters (so that all data it taken from buffer cache) do you still see the slowness? What is the raw disk speed? Is it a dedicated server?

Comment: Does block have a default size of 8k (run `show block_size` to figure out)?

Comment: @RomanKonoval I see... Yes, second time it is much faster for the same IDs (and even already processed range of IDs). I will request raw disk speed from admins. I only know it is iSCSI storage and server is virtual machine under Hyper-V.

Comment: show block_size == 8192

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179140/discussion-between-roman-konoval-and-greatvovan).

Comment: @RomanKonoval added "Update 2", may be it gives some clues...